# How to create a Radial Dial menu in a Website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to create a Radial Dial type menu, similar to the picture here (the highlighted top section should be on hover):

[image: Radial Dial]

Googling about radial menu or radial dial menu doesn't result to anything similar to this.

I am currently using Elementor pro with WordPress. So I can add custom HTML/CSS/JavaScript as well if required.

I was thinking of creating 3-4 buttons and then somehow try to transform them into a semi circle and then position them together. However that creates a lot of manual effort of resizing everything if a menu items is added/removed. Also, it will be a nightmare to make the website responsive.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SVG for your radial buttons, with a little js to handle the onclicks.

I created this svg code from adobe illustrator, but you may be able to find online svg code generators if you don't have adobe illustrator.

See example below with css hovers using ids on `PATH`s... you can use classes and other html attributes to get your desired result...

```css
PATH {
  fill: gray;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

PATH:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

PATH#option_a:hover {
  fill: red;
}

PATH#option_b:hover {
  fill: green;
}

PATH#option_c:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 1200">
  <path id="option_a" d="M600.5,104.1c-276.1,0-500,223.9-500,500h100c0-220.9,179.1-400,400-400s400,179.1,400,400h100c0-276.1-223.9-500-500-500Z"/>
  <path id="option_b" d="M600.5,1004.1v100c276.1,0,500-223.9,500-500h-100c0,220.9-179.1,400-400,400Z"/>
  <path id="option_c" d="M200.5,604.1H100.5c0,276.1,223.9,500,500,500v-100c-220.9,0-400-179.1-400-400Z"/>
</svg>
```

---

Answer to your comment, yeah sure so many things are possible with SVG. Though I am not guna lie, having Adobe Illustrator as tool makes SVG design a lot easier!

So I added arrows to my original SVG code (using Adobe Illustrator), and then created new SVG file code including arrows. From this new SVG code I took the `d` attribute from my `path`s and added them to my original SVG `path`s as a `data-d` attribute...

Then using a little jQuery, on `path` hover, I switch the current  `d` attribute with my `data-d` attribute...

```js
// on ready
$(function() {

  // on any segment mouse enter path
  $('.segment').on('mouseenter', function(e) {

    // temporally store hover-state data-d attribute coordinates
    let d = $(this).attr('data-d');

    // override data-d attribute value with original d attribute coordinates
    $(this).attr('data-d', $(this).attr('d'));

    // set d attribute with temporally stored hover-state coordinates
    $(this).attr('d', d);

  // on any segment mouse leave path
  }).on('mouseleave', function(e) {

    // temporally store original-state data-d attribute coordinates
    let d = $(this).attr('data-d');

    // override data-d attribute value with hover-state d attribute coordinates
    $(this).attr('data-d', $(this).attr('d'));

    // set d attribute with temporally stored original-state coordinates
    $(this).attr('d', d);

  });

});
```

```css
SVG {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

PATH {
  fill: gray;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

PATH:hover {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

PATH#segment_r:hover {
  fill: red;
}

PATH#segment_g:hover {
  fill: green;
}

PATH#segment_b:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 1200">
  <path 
    class="segment"
    id="segment_r" 
    d="M600.5,104.1c-276.1,0-500,223.9-500,500h100c0-220.9,179.1-400,400-400s400,179.1,400,400h100c0-276.1-223.9-500-500-500Z"
    data-d="M630.4,105l-29.9-29.9L570.6,105c-262.2,15.5-470.1,233-470.1,499.1h100c0-220.9,179.1-400,400-400
    s400,179.1,400,400h100C1100.5,338,892.6,120.4,630.4,105z"
  />
  <path 
    class="segment"
    id="segment_g"
    d="M600.5,1004.1v100c276.1,0,500-223.9,500-500h-100c0,220.9-179.1,400-400,400Z"
    data-d="M974.6,935.9c78.4-88.3,125.9-204.5,125.9-331.8h-100c0,220.9-179.1,400-400,400v100
    c127.3,0,243.5-47.6,331.8-125.9h42.3V935.9z"
  />
  <path 
    class="segment"
    id="segment_b" 
    d="M200.5,604.1H100.5c0,276.1,223.9,500,500,500v-100c-220.9,0-400-179.1-400-400Z"
    data-d="M600.5,1004.1c-220.9,0-400-179.1-400-400h-100c0,127.3,47.6,243.5,125.9,331.8v42.3h42.3
    c88.3,78.4,204.5,125.9,331.8,125.9V1004.1z"
  />
</svg>
```

Here is fiddle version... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/f9wg57u1/

I love SVG code. So much is possible.

My example is probably a little heavy (hence using JS), I'm sure someone could recreate this with pure SVG and CSS.

But Adobe Illustrator makes things so much easier from a visual design point of view when creating SVG's.

> Update: I've changed the `path` hover state cursor to `crosshair` so
> you can see how the segment arrow is also included in the hover area
> before `mouseleave` event.

Comment: Thanks, Idk why I never thought about svg to approach this before. Is there a possibility to make a pointer arrow on the dial (like in the picture) on hover on the SVG? Sorry I don't have Illustrator. I might use some online tool

Comment: @RitZz added update to my answer with a little 'off topic' jquery to show you what is possible.